# How to trim video in jectpack compose with custom slider to select start and the end point in the video

Tags: android, video, android-jetpack-compose, slider, android-mediaplayer

I'm working on a project in compose and it requires trimming video. I have implemented the video trimming part but I having issues with creating the slider to select the starting and the ending point with the chunks of the video on it.

I have tried to use the video editor [Here](https://github.com/UmairOye/Video-Trimmer) to

```
DisposableEffect(
 AndroidView(
    factory = { context ->
        VideoEditor(context)
    }
)
```

It works fine with xml but it not working fine in Compose. So I want to create a custom one in compose.

[image]